# Поднять сервер wsl2 + ubuntu

Tags: linux, веб-сервер, настройка, веб-сайт

Хочу избежать хостингов и поднять свой веб-сервер. Пользуюсь **ubuntu 20.08**, поднятой на **wsl2** (подсистема **win10**), на ПК. Есть "белый" ip, есть домен, прикреплённый к этому ip, дистрибутивы для классического lamp-сервера - загружены.
Отдельную машинку под линукс купить не могу. А локальный - не интересно (почти все ссылки указывают на поднятие именно *локального* сервера).
Примеры:
https://g-ek.com/ustanovka-lokalnogo-veb-servera-v-wsl-windows10

https://help.ubuntu.ru/wiki/apachemysqlphp

Прошу подсказать настройки или туториал для поднятия оного (могучий google подсказал только локальные варианты).

Comment: Может я что-то не то делал, но `apt install ssh dokuwiki` в лоб у меня не отработал, когда пытался ковырнуть wsl на 20h2. Мой совет - ставь virtualbox и не парь мозг - там точно всё пашет.

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл решение.

1. Нужна любая настройка сервера ***'LAMP'*** на ***wsl***(2) для локального хоста, белый (***внешний*** IP).
   (https://g-ek.com/ustanovka-lokalnogo-veb-servera-v-wsl-windows10)
2. Добейтесь вывода на localhost(::8080 у кого-то, я через .hosts поднимал и разворачивал сначала? так что описываю именно свой случай)
   3)На "припаркованный" домен записываю "А-запись", в которой указываю IP, данный мне провайдером (узнать свой ip я могу либо из командной строки ***ipconfig***  либо через настройки win10,либо каб-т провайдера, вариантов много).

4)Узнать ip ubuntu (что-то типа ip a), скопировать данные в powershell в команду *netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 listenaddress=0.0.0.0 connectport=443 connectaddress=ххх.ххх.ххх.ххх* listenaddress - не трогаем, это что-то типа "слушай все порты". *connectaddress* - тот ip из линуксоида что нужно вставить. Три команды отдельно под каждый *listenport* (22, 80, 443) Я не уверен, работает ли кома, если перечислять listenport

5. Своему ПК (или операционке) задайте статический ip и занесите в свой роутер.
   [image: пример переадресации портов(обрезаный скрин)]Настройте брандмауэр Windows и роутера ( у меня на роутере ещё брандмауэр, будьте внимательны)
6. Если что-то явно не выходит - попробуйте, следуя схеме, подумать.[image: Схема работы запроса в сети - из сети].

Будут вопросы - пишите, постараюсь ответить, не судите строго - я новенький. :)